# Flutter application with android fails to capture callback url

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to authenticate a flutter application against Spotify.
For this, I use the `flutter_web_auth` package. I have a button to authenticate against Spotify.
Once user clicks the button, the following function operates:

```
onPressed: () async {
  final spotifyAuthURL = Uri.https(
    'accounts.spotify.com',
    '/authorize',
    {
      'response_type': 'code',
      'client_id': dotenv.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID'),
      'redirect_uri':
          'https://vinyl_app_spotify.com/callback',
      'scope': 'user-read-private user-read-email',
    },
  );

  final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
    url: spotifyAuthURL.toString(),
    callbackUrlScheme:
        'https://vinyl_app_spotify.com/callback',
  );
},
```

I've also added the following activiy to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file as I should have done according to the `flutter_web_auth` package:

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" >
    <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https://vinyl_app_spotify.com/callback" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So after I click my application button, I do get access to Spotify, then the redirect url kicks in, but I just see this:
[image]

So my android emulator could not capture the callback url.

What is my mistake? Any advice..

Comment: Are you sure http://vinyl_app_spotify.com/ is the correct url?

Comment: @MikkelT What do you mean by correct url? This is the arbitrary custom url I chose

Comment: Yeah but you shouldn't use an arbitrary URL, you should use a URL that returns a callback action. Edit: ah sorry, maybe I misunderstood. Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665796/android-handle-oauth-callback-using-intent-filter

Comment: @MikkelT Spotify allows only http/s schemas for redirect url